# Storing data files on Pentaho Repository

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-spoon, pentaho-data-integration

I am working with Pentaho products: Pentaho Data Integration (PDI) and Pentaho Server.

From PDI, I could create connection to the Pentaho Repository running on a Pentaho Server. I already created some jobs or transformations, stored them in Repository and they're all well-executed.

However when I configurate the input/ output sources of jobs/ transformations, I could only use data files from my local machine. Is there any way that I can store data files on Repository, and configurate the jobs/ transformations to read data from them?

Thank you so much.

P/s: I am working with PDI v9.3 CE and Pentaho Server v9.3 CE.

Comment: For more information, I read some docs about Files Repository, but that repo is still initiated from a local folder. And also when I browse files to be loaded in transformations/ jobs, the files in Files Repository are not displayed.

Answer (score 0):

This is one of the solution I found.

For each transformation/ job stored on Pentaho Repository, there are 3 running configurations: pentaho local, pentaho server, pentaho slave.

Pentaho local: execute trans/job on the machine being used. That means the trans/job can only read & write data in local storage.

Pentaho server: execute trans/job on the machine hosting Pentaho Server (also Pentaho Repository), wih this running mode, trans/job can read & write data in server's storage

Pentaho slave: execute trans/job using slave server's resource.

So, in my case, the solution is switching running config of trans/job to Pentaho Server config.